# Flutter: how to order list by dateTime

Tags: flutter

I have a list like this:

```
var orderedEvents = [
{
 "realTime": "2021-07-28 12:00:02.000" // Flutter dateTime but saved as String
},
{
 "realTime": "2021-07-28 12:00:00.000"
},
{
 "realTime": "2021-07-28 12:00:01.000"
}
];
```

And I do:

```
orderedEvents.sort((a, b) {
      final realTimeA = DateTime.parse(a["realTime"]);
      final realTimeB = DateTime.parse(b["realTime"]);
      return realTimeA.isBefore(realTimeB) ? -1 : 1;
    });
```

But it's not ordered properly obtaining 0, 2 and 1.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue. Please provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure to convert from Strings to DateTimes.

Afterward, simply use the following:

```
orderedEvents.sort((a,b) {
  final realTimeA = DateTime.parse(a["realTime"]);
  final realTimeB = DateTime.parse(b["realTime"]);
  return realTimeA.compareTo(realTimeB);
});
```

Comment: For whatever reason, the isBefore method was working but that seemed to work.
PS: you need to change last line to return realTimeA.compareTo(realTimeB);

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed the typos.